# Microscopic interpretation of constant voltage from Battery

Tags: voltage, chemical-potential, electrochemistry, chemical-compounds

I don't know if this is the right place to ask(Maybe it's more related to chemistry), but this has been troubling me for some while. 
Consider you have a chemical cell. Then the reason for the constant voltage must be the difference of V between

1. The voltage at the molecule which the electron is coming from(The reactant), and
2. The voltage at the molecule which the electron is going to. (The product)

I don't understand why this voltage difference is constant. With a lot of external variables, I would think this could differ a lot from the arrangement of the surrounding molecules, etc. Maybe it's a matter of scale, and those things don't matter at the molecular level..

Comment: I don't think those are the reactant and the product. Product molecules are the same atoms as the reactant molecules but with different bonds.

Comment: This might be a better question for the [chemistry stackexchange site](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: https://www.science.org.au/curious/technology-future/batteries